# How to get the DisplayMember value in the DrawItem event of a comboBox? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Please consider the following:

I populate my comboBox using the following method:

```
void populateComboBox()
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = GetDataTableSource(); // some data table used as source
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";            // string
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";                // id is an int

    // Suppose I have this data in my comboBox after populating it
    // 
    //
    // id (ValueMember) | name (DisplayMember)
    // -----------------------------------------
    //  1       | name1
    //  2       | name2
    //  3       | name3
}
```

In `DrawItem` event, I want to get the value of the `DisplayMember` (name) of the comboBox and assign it to some variable.
So far, I got this code and it seems not to work... Please have it corrected. Thanks in advance....

```
void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    string name = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(comboBox1.SelectedValue = e.Index))["name"].ToString();

    // do something
    //  
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Ok, i just came across this problem myself and here is an even better answer:

```
string displayValue = this.GetItemText(this.Items[e.Index]);             
g.DrawString(displayValue, e.Font, br, e.Bounds.Left, y + 1);
```

Per MSDN:

> If the DisplayMember property is not specified, the value returned by
>   GetItemText is the value of the item's ToString method. Otherwise, the
>   method returns the string value of the member specified in the
>   DisplayMember property for the object specified in the item parameter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

how about using just combobox item, it is selected displayed value:

```
string name = (string)comboBox1.Items[e.Index];
```

If you getting `e.Index = -1`, change `DrawMode = OwnerDrawVariable` and `DropDownStyle = DropDown`

**EDIT:**

Ok I understood whats wrong. I tested with strings as datasource, so in your code should work this:

```
string name = ((DataRowView)comboBox1.Items[e.Index])["name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a really generic function you could elaborate a bit:

Lets say you have two comboboxes, one containing items based of custom collection A with DisplayMember AA and the other contains items based on custom collection B with DisplayMember BB:

How could a generic function know which value to return? Based of DisplayMember of course, but you don't want to pass AA / BB to a generic function if you want it generic.

So

```
[anItemTheCombobox.GetType().GetProperty(theCombobox.DisplayMember).GetValue(theCombobox, null)];
```

Background

I used it in a generic function called calculateAndSetWidth. The function loops through all items in listbox to determine the maxWidth:

```
public void calculateAndSetWidth(ListBox listbox, int minWidth = 0) {
Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
int maxWidth = 0;
SizeF mySize = null;

foreach (object item in listbox.Items) {
    mySize = graphics.MeasureString(item.GetType().GetProperty(listbox.DisplayMember).GetValue(item, null), listbox.Font);
    if (mySize.Width > maxWidth) {
        maxWidth = mySize.Width;
    }
}

listbox.Width = Math.Max(maxWidth, minWidth);
```

}